# realmd vs authconfig

Tags: rhel, active-directory

What is the difference in functionality between realmd and authconfig?
(using fedora 22)
What is the correct way to connect to an active directory realm with using Kerberos and using SSSD server?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I unterstood, realmd is kind of a frontend to all those programs helping you the join the domain without having to adapt all the configuration manually. authconfig is a configuraion wizard too, but it wouln't join the domain.

I am using realmd for 2 years now with good experiences :)

The command we use is

```
realmd -U <AD_User_that_has_the_permissions_to_join> join mydomain.com
```

That's it

Comment: I am not sure on how important the order of command and options was, it might only work that way:
`realm join -U <AD_User_that_has_the_permissions_to_join> mydomain.com`